# How to enable sorting for programmatically added DataGridTextColumn in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 2 fixed columns that can be sorted without any problem.

```
            <DataGrid Name="SelectedObjectsGrid"
                      Visibility="{Binding ShowSelectedObjectsInfoPanel, Converter={StaticResource BoolNegationToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedObjectItems}"
                      SelectionMode="Extended"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="0,0,4,0">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Style}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource SelectedObjectRowContextMenu}" />
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="SelectedObjectsRow_DoubleClick" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{ui:CommandHandler ObjectsGridSelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,ElementName=SelectedObjectsGrid}">
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Name.IsExpanded}"
                                                      Tag="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                                      Background="#FF112255" BorderBrush="#FF002255"
                                                      Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                                <Expander.ContextMenu>
                                                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrKeepSelectionTableShort}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler KeepTable}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" />
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrRemoveSelectionTableShort}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler RemoveTable}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" />
                                                        <Separator/>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrList}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ToggleSelectedObjectsGrouping}" CommandParameter="False" >
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Image>
                                                                    <Image.Source>
                                                                        <DrawingImage>
                                                                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, 
                                                                                    Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolNegationToGeometryConverter}}" />
                                                                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                                        </DrawingImage>
                                                                    </Image.Source>
                                                                </Image>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrGroups}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ToggleSelectedObjectsGrouping}" CommandParameter="True" >
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Image>
                                                                    <Image.Source>
                                                                        <DrawingImage>
                                                                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, 
                                                                                    Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGeometryConverter}}" />
                                                                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                                        </DrawingImage>
                                                                    </Image.Source>
                                                                </Image>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                        <Separator Visibility="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrHintTreeExpandAll}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ExpandOrCollapseAll}" CommandParameter="True" 
                                                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.SelectedObjectsGroupHeaders.DoCollapsedGroupsExist, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameToBitmapSource}}" DataContext="BmpTreeExpandAll"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrHintTreeCollapseAll}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ExpandOrCollapseAll}" CommandParameter="False"  
                                                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.SelectedObjectsGroupHeaders.DoExpandedGroupsExist, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameToBitmapSource}}" DataContext="BmpTreeCollapseAll"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                    </ContextMenu>
                                                </Expander.ContextMenu>
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <DockPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name.Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                                            <Run Text=" ("/>
                                                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name.GroupedCount, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                                            <Run Text=")"/>
                                                        </TextBlock>
                                                    </DockPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <Expander.Content>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                </Expander.Content>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource XpStrLabel}" Binding="{Binding Data.Label}" SortDirection="Ascending"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource XpStrClass}" Binding="{Binding Data.Class.Name}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

When program is properly initialized I call method below to add dynamic columns that can't be sorted:

I have piece of code that adds:

```
    private void AddDynamicColumns()
    {
        var separator = new char[] {';', ':'};
        foreach (var parameter in Parameters.Instance.GetParameters("SelectedObjectsDynField"))
        {
            var values = parameter.StringValue.Split(separator);
            var fieldName = values[0];
            var fieldDescr = fieldName;
            if (values.Length > 1)
                fieldDescr = values[1];

            var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
            col.CanUserSort = true;
            col.Header = fieldDescr;
            var bind = new MultiBinding();
            bind.Converter = new NetObjectToPrintableFieldValueConverter();
            bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Data"));
            bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding() { Source = fieldName });
            col.Binding = bind;
            SelectedObjectsGrid.Columns.Add(col); 
        }
    }
```

What could be the reason for this?

EDIT: Adding

```
col.SortMemberPath = fieldName
```

makes it somewhat work, but it breaks virtualization. Populating DataGrid takes now 20 times longer. Also the sorting does not sort rows correctly. Clicking 2nd time dynamic column to sort it descending does nothing.

Comment: Are the added types implement ``IComparable``?

Comment: Data in bound properties for columns are either integer or string. See my edit about losing virtualization and sorting incorrectly.

Comment: This is a known problem. see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34864070/5615980

Comment: Thanks! WPF DataGrid really sucks. My guess is that it will never be ready. Hello worlds are nice and easy but anything involving anything even remotely complex is virtually impossible to implement. Even by experienced developers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864070/5615980), setting the `RowHeight` makes the `WPF DataGrid` not lose virtualization when is sorted by specific columns.

Comment: thanks, i just tried it but didn't have any effect in my datagrid. the height was affected but virtualization was still lost with .NET Framework 4.5.1